# Matrix equation using determinant

Tags: matrix-equations

This question got me thinking and confused on how to solve it.
If $$\begin{align}k(x-a)+2x-z&=0\\k(y-a)+2y-z&=0 \\ k(z-a)-x-y+2z&=0\end{align}$$

Show that $$x = \frac{ak(k+3)}{k^2+4k+2}.$$

So far so good, I could only solve it simultaneously.

Comment: Where's your work?  If you could solve it simultaneously, that's a start.  Let's see what you've done?

Comment: It's weird that that only $x,z$ are in the first equation and $y,z$ in the second.

Comment: This can be made a matrix equation: $$\begin{pmatrix}2+k&0&-1\\0&2+k&-1 \\-1&-1&2+k\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}ka\\ka\\ka\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @amwh, this question required proving using determinant method. Solving it using simultaneous method is not enough. So that's why your help will be appreciated

Comment: @thomas Andrew, which methods will be most suitable to use? Will determinant method do?

Comment: I don't know what you are calling the "determinant method," sorry.

Comment: I mean what method of solving system of equation like this should I employ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The “determinant method” might be Cramer’s Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforward, using Cramer’s rule, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems:
$$\begin{align}
{}&\det\begin{pmatrix}
2+k&0&-1\\
0&2+k &-1\\
-1&-1&2+k
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=(2+k)^2\det\begin{pmatrix} 
1&0&-1/(2+k)\\
0&1 &-1/(2+k)\\
-1&-1&2+k
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=(2+k)^2\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-1/(2-k)\\
0&1 &-1/(2+k)\\
0&-1&2+k-1/(2+k)
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=(2+k)^2\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-1/(2-k)\\
0&1 &-1/(2+k)\\
0&0&2+k-2/(2+k)
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\qquad=(2+k)^2(2+k-2/(2+k))\\
&\qquad=(k+2)(k^2+4k +2)=:D.
\end{align}$$
Now
$$\begin{align}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
ka&0&-1\\ ka &2+k&-1\\ ka &-1&2+k
\end{pmatrix}
&=ka\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-1\\ 1&2+k&-1\\ 1&-1&2+k
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=ka\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\ 1&2+k&0\\ 1&-1&3+k
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=ka(2+k)(3+k)=:D_x.
\end{align}
$$
Hence $x=D_x/D$ in case $k\notin\{-2,-2\pm\sqrt2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the system remains the same if you interchange $x$ and $y$. Therefore $x = y$ for any solution that is unique. This means that there are only two equations:
$$
k(x-a) + 2x - z = 0 \\
k(z-a) - 2x + 2z = 0 
$$ 
Solve the first equation for $z$, substitute into the second equation, and solve for $x$.